# $a \le b \le c$ and $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ such that they are side lengths of a triangle one of whose angle is $60^\circ$.

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Determine all triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers with $a \le b \le c$ and $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ such that they are side lengths of a triangle one of whose angle is $60^\circ$.

---

Here if we assume that the angle between sides with lengths $b$ and $c$ is $60^\circ$, then we have

$$a^2 = b^2+c^2-2bc \cos(60^\circ)$$ and hence $a^2 = b^2+c^2-bc$.

---

I am not able to proceed after that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving for $z^2 = x^2 -xy + y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162231/solving-for-z2-x2-xy-y2) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E2%3Db%5E2-bc%2Bc%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). Note the search results also include the more general [Quadratic Diophantine Equation $x^2 + axy + y^2 = z^2$](/q/823199).

Comment: If $a\le b\le c$, then the 60$^\circ$ angle has to be between sides with length $a$ and $c$, actually.